# Show that $\frac{1}{x+y}\leq\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{y+z}+1$

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem, if $x\neq y\neq z\neq 0$, with $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$. If we define $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ as, $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \qquad 0 \qquad\qquad, x=y\\ 1+\dfrac{1}{x+y}\qquad , x\neq y\end{cases}$$ I need prove that $f(x,y)\leq f(x,z)+f(y,z)$.

My attemp, Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{N}$ differents, then I need prove that $$\dfrac{1}{x+y}\leq\dfrac{1}{x+z}+\dfrac{1}{y+z}+1$$

My idea was find some inequalities, that maybe can help me, for instance $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}\geq\dfrac{2}{x+y}$, but if I take $x=m+n$ and $y=n+k$, then $$\dfrac{1}{m+k}+\dfrac{1}{n+k}\geq\dfrac{2}{m+n+2k}$$

If I prove that $\dfrac{2}{m+n+2k}>\dfrac{1}{m+n}$ I finished the problem, but this implies that $0>2k$, but $k\in\mathbb{N}$ So, I don't know how prove this, Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the left side is always less than $1$, whereas the right side is greater than $1$.

Comment: mm ok, This problem was proposed in class, my teacher define a metric $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, so the problem is show that the triangle inequality. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not a metric, since $f(x, x) > 0$. I'm not sure what your teacher was intending.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot mentioned the cases when $x= y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that the left hand side of inequality is always less than or equal to 1. So the given inequality follows.